# How to pass value from a constant variable inside a component to another component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to send the value of 'name' to another component, say the other component is called 'Header' as follow:

Snippet of the code:

```
const OrganizationProfile = () => {
  const organizationId = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const { orgProfileState, orgProfileDispatch } = useContext(
    OrganizationContext,
  );
  const { error, loading, organization } = orgProfileState;

  const {
    name,
    email,
    location,
    needs,
    about = "",
    objectives = {},
    urls = {},
  } = organization || {};
  console.log(name); // prints out name of organisation
<Header name={name} /> // --< the problem
```

I get this error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions" by the way i imported 'import Header from "../Header"

is it because maybe the constant variable is inside the component function itself? any possible solutions ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get name directly from orgprofilestate like

const {  organization : { name}} = orgprofilestate

Comment: Iam able to get the name of the organisation put i want to pass the value of name from this component to another component so i can display it on the screen

Comment: You are alredy passing it, i think you cant just get in the other component..

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your Header component from inside your function :

```
const OrganizationProfile = () => {
   const organizationId = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const { orgProfileState, orgProfileDispatch } = useContext(
    OrganizationContext,
  );
  const { error, loading, organization } = orgProfileState;

  const {
    name,
    email,
    location,
    needs,
    about = "",
    objectives = {},
    urls = {},
  } = organization || {};
  console.log(name); // prints out name of organisation

return (
    <Header name={name} />
)
```

Comment: Hi @Raunak i tried that but then i won't be able to return anything after that which is an issue

Comment: as @Halim pointed out, you can wrap all the child components which you need to return inside a single <div> or a React Fragment </>

Answer (score 0):

as @Raunak Tibrewal said you need to wrap you  inside a return statement, you said you won't be able to return anything after it, i didn't get the full context but you can do this:

```
return(
  <>
   <Header name={name}
   <Body />
   <Footer/>
  </>
)
```